# Simple group of order 60

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why a simple group of order 60 does not contain a subgroup of order 15 and 20, but may include a subgroup of order 12?

Comment: Are you familiar with [an example of a simple group of order 60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ is a finite group and $H<G$, then the natural action of $G$ on $G/H$ induces an homomorphism
$$
G \to S_n
$$
where $n = [G:H]$. If $G$ is simple, this homomorphism must be injective. Now if $|G| = 60$, then $n\geq 5$, so $G$ cannot have a subgroup of smaller index.